# ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Mono" issue vb.net, c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, mono

I have followed 2 tutorials like [this](http://erictummers.wordpress.com/2012/01/25/target-mono-from-visual-studio/) to integrate [mono 2.10.8 profile](http://www.box.com/s/qligmtyer2log12k9027) in visual studio 2010

After doing all, when selecting mono profile I get some issues:

[image]

if I change the to .net 2 framework, I  have no problems:
[image]

- I Copied the contents of C:\Program Files\Mono-2.10.8\lib\mono\4.0 to 
  C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Mono.
- Created the folder RedistList and added FrameworkList.xml
- Added the key to registry....

Also tried to create a .net 4 project and then  select mono 2.8 profile as suggested, but have the same errors.

What am I missing?

Comment: There is no official support of full Mono profile in Visual Studio. So you'd better switch to MonoDevelop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chek [this page](http://www.mono-project.com/GettingStartedWithMonoTools),

**Installing Mono Tools for Visual Studio**

Requirements:

Windows XP, Vista, or 7, 32 or 64 bits
Visual Studio
2008 SP1 Standard or Professional, or
2010 Professional, Premium, or Ultimate